# video embedding in xhtml

Tags: xhtml, blogs, video-embedding

I am trying to customize a theme in tumblr so that it embeds videos in their full scale in a blog, but i can't seem to do it...

here are the instances in the code that refer to video

```
.video-post .video {margin-bottom:1.5em;}


{block:Video}
<div class="content video-post">
  <div class="video">{Video-500}</div>

  {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
</div>
{/block:Video}
```

i tried some basic stuff like removing the -500 and/or adding height="100%"; width="100%" at some places but it does not work that way..

Answer (score 0):

See http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos or http://fitvidsjs.com/